# iMac fails to boot - graphics issue?

Tags: imac, startup, graphics, gpu

I'm having an issue with a 2017 iMac - it doesn't boot - crashes about half way through Apple logo progress bar, often with some funny graphics displaying - e.g. half the screen is yellow.

I've reset NVRAM/PRAM/SMC, wiped hard disks and installed Big Sur, then upgrade to Monterey.  Still I'm getting the same issue.

It does boot fine in safe mode...

I'm suspecting graphics card failure.  I received these details on one failed start, can anybody help diagnose please?

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7facc1f244): "virtual bool IOAccelLegacyDisplayMachine::display_mode_did_change(uint32_t): AMDRadeonAccelerator driver returns false" @IOAccelLegacyDisplayMachine.cpp:267
Panicked task 0xffffff855221a3e0: 10 threads: pid 143: WindowServer
Backtrace (CPU 0), panicked thread: 0xffffff855177fcd0, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffe0970a3600 : 0xffffff801489c00d 
0xffffffe0970a3650 : 0xffffff80149f5d85 
0xffffffe0970a3690 : 0xffffff80149e5763 
0xffffffe0970a36e0 : 0xffffff801483ba60 
0xffffffe0970a3700 : 0xffffff801489c3dd 
0xffffffe0970a3820 : 0xffffff801489bb96 
0xffffffe0970a3880 : 0xffffff8015118649 
0xffffffe0970a38f0 : 0xffffff7facc1f244 
0xffffffe0970a3900 : 0xffffff7facbc7eee 
0xffffffe0970a3940 : 0xffffff7facc11180 
0xffffffe0970a3980 : 0xffffff7facd74c70 
0xffffffe0970a3ac0 : 0xffffff7facd5f195 
0xffffffe0970a3b50 : 0xffffff7facd6a627 
0xffffffe0970a3b70 : 0xffffff7facd6f3c9 
0xffffffe0970a3bf0 : 0xffffff7f95614a80 
0xffffffe0970a3c20 : 0xffffff7facd64fb8 
0xffffffe0970a3cb0 : 0xffffff801502957c 
0xffffffe0970a3d10 : 0xffffff80150968d3 
0xffffffe0970a3d70 : 0xffffff801499f007 
0xffffffe0970a3dc0 : 0xffffff8014876cf9 
0xffffffe0970a3e50 : 0xffffff801488dd89 
0xffffffe0970a3ee0 : 0xffffff80149caaf2 
0xffffffe0970a3fa0 : 0xffffff801483c246 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(593.0)[D7EBF011-CEEF-3DF8-BD85-6CCE427455B7]@0xffffff7facd54000->0xffffff7facd82fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[5E1B0BE0-4B73-35F5-9126-EB05FBB8BAF5]@0xffffff80173ee000->0xffffff8017418fff
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(462.4)[37BACF45-3C71-3411-97DB-E9AA07F37D0E]@0xffffff7facbc7000->0xffffff7facc30fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[BB7769F7-6389-3ABC-A6CF-2BC079FA7BF8]@0xffffff8015f6f000->0xffffff8015f90fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(593)[D7EBF011-CEEF-3DF8-BD85-6CCE427455B7]@0xffffff7facd54000->0xffffff7facd82fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[5E1B0BE0-4B73-35F5-9126-EB05FBB8BAF5]@0xffffff80173ee000->0xffffff8017418fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[81D7D4E0-A39C-332D-A4A4-AEBB70A9B6FF]@0xffffff801742a000->0xffffff801742cfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(302.9)[F42646DD-8963-3EA4-BAC3-2D0F36CDA224]@0xffffff801755d000->0xffffff8017579fff
         com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer(4.0.7)[0E573FD7-F1EF-3237-86D1-12C11C80C1FA]@0xffffff7f95613000->0xffffff7f95638fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[7EF77A11-B2B8-3CCF-9188-597E1279EDAC]@0xffffff8016f48000->0xffffff8016f49fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(593)[D7EBF011-CEEF-3DF8-BD85-6CCE427455B7]@0xffffff7facd54000->0xffffff7facd82fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[5E1B0BE0-4B73-35F5-9126-EB05FBB8BAF5]@0xffffff80173ee000->0xffffff8017418fff
            dependency: com.apple.kext.AMDSupport(4.0.7)[61E40B4A-8B3E-3569-85EB-250CD91E8EB1]@0xffffff7fab20d000->0xffffff7fab2d7fff

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff855177fcd0): WindowServer

Mac OS version:
21A559

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 17:33:23 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 19BD4E1B-0268-3EE0-BC66-91F035BC9429
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000014600000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8014800000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000014610000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8014810000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8014700000
System model name: iMac18,2 (Mac-77F17D7DA9285301)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11656145872
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x00000002b6c2ae6a
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000e05726742 0x0000000000000000
Zone info:
Foreign   : 0xffffff802afb3000 - 0xffffff802afc0000
Native    : 0xffffff804309e000 - 0xffffffa04309e000
Readonly  : 0 - 0
Metadata  : 0xffffffe7be2c3000 - 0xffffffe7de444000
Bitmaps   : 0xffffffe7de444000 - 0xffffffe7e4444000
last started kext at 9537884636: >AudioAUUC 1.70 (addr 0xffffff7facac5000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   125
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    4.0.7
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    4.0.7
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.15
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.434
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.7
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
@kext.AMD9500!C 4.0.7
>!A!IKBLGraphics    18.0.2
>eficheck   1
>AGDCBacklightControl   6.4.9
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.4.9
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
@UVCService 1
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.4.9
>!ASMCLMU   212
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  126.40.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!A!IKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 18.0.2
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    5010.1
>!UTopCaseDriver    5010.1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   582.40.4
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1933.41.2
>!ASDXC 3.1.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  11.0.0
>!AAHCIPort 351
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    402
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
@kext.triggers  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4200HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  4.0.7
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.0
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.7
>!UAudio    412.8
>!AAudioClockLibs   100.9.1
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  593
>!AGraphicsControl  6.4.9
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOAudio!F  300.10
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
|IOAVB!F    1010.2
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1000.11
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
>!AIPAppender   1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  6.4.9
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   462.4
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.4.9
|IOGraphics!F   593
>!AHS!BDriver   5010.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
>!AMultitouchDriver 5400.25
>!AInputDeviceSupport   5400.30
>!AHIDKeyboard  228
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.0
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.0
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  302.9
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
|IOAHCIBlock!S  333
|IO80211!FLegacy    1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>corecapture    1.0.4
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IOAHCI!F   295
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1000.11
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  532.40.7
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  209.40.6
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  452.30.4
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  452.30.4
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   4.1.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0
```

Comment: When my iMac graphics failed it would not make the screen work in **any** mode. I got the data off by target disk mode. Then had it repaired.

Answer (score 1):

This panic signature:

> panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7facc1f244): "virtual bool IOAccelLegacyDisplayMachine::display_mode_did_change(uint32_t): AMDRadeonAccelerator driver returns false" @IOAccelLegacyDisplayMachine.cpp:267

along with this fact:

> It does boot fine in safe mode...

strongly implicates the graphics stack in the failure sequence, since the panic signature is inside the accelerated graphics driver and this driver is disabled in Safe Boot.

The fact that your standard troubleshooting practices, including a full OS reinstall, failed to remediate the issue gives strong support to a hardware failure.

**How to test this:** I expect that if you run **[Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)** (hold <kbd>D</kbd> during boot) you will see an error.

GPU HW failure does happen to a steady percentage of machines over time and there's nothing that you can do to resolve it yourself on an integrated machine such as the iMac.

**--> Conclusion: You should bring your machine to Apple for hardware service.**